# mongo db installation disappears when i try to run the msi file in Windows

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, backend

I tried to intstall mongodb but mongo db installation disappears when i try to run the msi file in Windows.I also included the bin  path in the environment variable.

Comment: You mean the **installation** window disappears? Did you run as Admin?

Comment: yeah it disappears after i try to install the msi file